# printf variable char multiple times

Tags: c, printf, ascii, repeat

I need to print a certain ASCII character, DOUBLE_HORIZONTAL_LINE(205) "═" 20 times. The file is encoded in unicode however, so I need to do something like `printf("%c", 205)`, which is fine, except I can't figure out how to repeat the char. I tried using `%1$c`, but that just printed "$c" literally.

```
printf("%1$c%1$c\n", 205); //205 = ASCII '═'
```

I expected the above code snippet to print ═ twice, instead it prints $c$c.

Do I really need to make a for i<20 printf loop?

Edit: trying to directly `printf("═");` will result in `ΓòÉ` being outputted. Again, because of the unicode-ascii conversion.

Comment: Try doing that in a loop.

Comment: If you use `%1$c` and get `$c`, that suggests your `printf()` implementation does not support the [POSIX `printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) extension with numbered argument conversion specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
char bar[21];
memset(bar, 205, 20);
bar[20] = '\0';
puts(bar);
```

As a bonus, this is more efficient than printf(), because the entire string is written to stdout at once.

Comment: This looked like it would work, but using a number throws off my compiler (gcc): 
`C:\Users\AC\Desktop\cli buffer.c:36:1: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'bar' [-Wimplicit-int]` and 
`C:\Users\AC\Desktop\cli buffer.c:36:1: error: conflicting types for 'bar'`.

Comment: Maybe you have another thing called `bar`?  Try using a different variable name.  The code is fine and works: https://godbolt.org/z/YTizh_

Comment: The issue turned out to be that it was outside of main. Thanks!